# Recorded vim macro saved to file and loaded again looks weird

Tags: vim, macros

I recorded a macro in register a.

I pasted it with `"ap` and it looks like:

[image]

Saving the file, quitting vim and loading it in a new vim instance the line is altered into:

[image]

Sorry for the graphics, I couldn't copy the lines.

What me also confuses is:
echo &enc = utf-8
echo &fenc = latin1
echo &ff = dos

where the following is defined in the _vimrc:
set ff=dos
set fenc=utf-8
set enc=utf-8

I'm trying to save some macros in a file and loading it again by copying in the register.
It works if I visual select the line, and copy it to register a`"ay`.
But as soon as I save the file and load it in a new instance of vim the macro lines look weird.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Macros store key codes and key codes have strange representations when echoed to a terminal. `^M` is <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `^[` is <kbd>Esc</kbd>, arrow keys look even more strange.

The bottom line: don't look at macros, just create, store and use them.